# Does a Thread timeout or Thread.Sleep() for longtime close or abort a thread?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have a windows Service that start some tasks based on a configuration.

Each task start on its own thread, some tasks runes once per day.

I'm using `Thread.Sleep()` and calculate the time for the next run.

The problem is that sometimes after 2 or 3 days the service is still running but some tasks just dont run.

The sleep period is right, everything is working fine and I am not getting any exceptions.

Is there anything that could make a thread stop or the sleep method abort the thread?

this is the main function of the thread

```
private void TaskLifeCycle()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create task object.
            Type taskType = Type.GetType(this.ConfigurationElement.Task);
            DebtLogic.Service.BackgroundTask bgTask = Activator.CreateInstance(taskType) as BackgroundTask;
            bgTask.Context = this;
            FireEvent(CreatedEventKey, new BackgroundTaskEventArgs(bgTask));
            FireEvent(InitilizingEventKey, new BackgroundTaskEventArgs(bgTask));
            bgTask.Initilize();
            FireEvent(InitilizedEventKey, new BackgroundTaskEventArgs(bgTask));
                // while the thread is alive, and did not abort then run.
            while (this.CurrentThread.IsAlive)
            {
                try
                {
                    //can run then block
                    if (CanRun(bgTask))
                    {
                        Run(bgTask);
                    }
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    FireEvent(ErrorEventKey,new BackgroundTaskErrorArgs(ex) );
                }
            }
            bgTask.Dispose();
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            FireEvent(ErrorEventKey, new BackgroundTaskErrorArgs(ex));
        }
    }
 private bool CanRun(BackgroundTask bgTask)
    {
        if (this.ConfigurationElement.EventBasedTask)
        {
            return bgTask.CanRun();
        }
        TimeSpan time;
        if (this.ConfigurationElement.Time != TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            time = this.ConfigurationElement.Time - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            if (time.TotalMilliseconds < 0)
                time = time.Add(new TimeSpan(24, 0, 0));
        }
        else
        {
            time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, this.ConfigurationElement.Interval);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(time);
        return bgTask.CanRun();
    }
```

the Run and Initialize methods are abstract methods that calls the task

Comment: If you share some code that shows your thread start and the basic implementation of your threadworker including your exception handling your question might get an answer. The only thing now left to do is guess...

Comment: I don't think such long `sleep`s deal well with power-saving hibernation etc. I wouldn't ever `sleep` longer than about a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a thread that sleeps for a long time. Make a short thread that sleeps a very short time (1 minute) and each time checks if enough time has passed since the last execution. This is much more robust and lets you track if your system is 'still alive'

Comment: thx so much, i've changed the timeout to 1 min, and check it works fine. duuno what was the issue but it is working now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `OS` let you for such a long sleep. Either it was possible you need to change your design. A slept thread at least consumes ~1 MB of RAM (for it's context).

Try using `System.Threading.Timer` or implement your own scheduling class with your requirements.